# How to initialize a Map in ES6/ES2015 similar to an Object expression?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the equivalent of

```
var object = {
  'foo': 'bar',
  1: 42
}
```

using an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: See also [Does JavaScript have a Map literal notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35654495/1048572)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The closest you can get is:

```
let object = new Map([
  ['foo', 'bar'],
  ['1', 42]
]);
```

Important things to notice:

1. Object properties are identified by strings, while Map keys can be any value, so make sure all keys are strings in the input array.
2. Iterating a Map object yields entries by insertion order. That is not guaranteed for objects, so behavior might be different.

Comment: Surely `['1', 42]` should be `[1, 42]` or did you make it a string because that's what it would be were it still an Object?

Comment: Point 1 doesn't make sense. If the keys can be any value, then why should I make sure they are strings?

Comment: @zeroflagL - because the question is how to initialize a Map similar to an object, and object keys are always strings. If you want an equivalent, but as a Map, you need to use strings as well.

Comment: I had similar issue but as it could not work properly on every browser.
Please check compatibility table about that feature "Constructor argument: new Map(iterable)"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @Avlin - I wouldn't recommend using `Map` in a client side script anyway, and if it's IE11 you're targeting then you're going to be facing a lot of missing features. Instead use a polyfill or a transpiler to get stable functionality.

Comment: this seems pretty dumb, why not `new Map({foo: bar})`, i don't get it

Comment: @AlexanderMills - suggestions that don't work are dumb. Have some respect

Comment: @AlexanderMills reason being an object literal's entries are not guaranteed by insertion order.  In other words, you lose that aspect of maps by way of using an object.

Comment: I think in newer JS engines, the  order of keys is preserved, but perhaps they have to remain compliant with older engines.

Comment: Also note that in some cases we don't care about key order, in fact, the vast majority of the time.

Answer (score 17):

In modern browsers it can be as simple as:

```
new Map(Object.entries(object))
```

Comment: Note that because an object's key insertion order isn't guaranteed, you will lose that assertion.  `.entries` may return items in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

This NPM package called [map-literal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-literal) does exactly what you want.

`Object.entries()` and `new Map()` can make a `Map` object for you, but it cannot deal with nested structures. Therefore you will need to use a package for that.